# Semantic Representation for enlish sentences in Prolog

Tags: syntax, prolog, dcg

I am trying to get a semantic representation for English sentences by using a DCG in Prolog.

This is the outcome I should be aiming for:

```
?- s(Sem,[john,sleeps],[]).
Sem=sleeps(john).
```

This is my current status:

```
?- s(Sem, [john,sleeps],[]).
Sem = (sleeps,john).
```

My Problem is the following: I really do not have any idea how I am supposed to get my verb outside of the parenthesis. 
I am using a simple DCG:

```
s((VP,NP)) --> np(NP), vp(VP).
s((VP,NP,OBJ)) --> np(NP), vp(VP,OBJ).
np(NP) --> pn(NP). 
np(np(det(D),N)) --> det(D),n(N).
np(np(det(D),a(A),N)) --> det(D),a(A),n(N).
n(n(N)) --> cn(N). 
vp(V)--> iv(V).
vp(V,OBJ) --> tv(V), np(OBJ).

iv(sleeps) --> [sleeps].
tv(likes) --> [likes].
tv(hates) --> [hates].
det(the) --> [the].
det(a) --> [a].
a(red) --> [red].
a(green) --> [green].
cn(book) --> [book].
cn(table) --> [table].
pn(john) --> [john].
pn(mary) --> [mary].
```

I appreciate any help since I am still a beginner in programming, especially in prolog.

Comment: You can unify a list with a term using the `=../2` operator. `Term =.. [foo, a, b]` will yield `Term = foo(a,b)`. Forming a term with the parentheses isn't really helping your cause. ;)

Comment: You can find some hints in Chapter 4 of (http://www.mtome.com/Publications/PNLA/prolog-digital.pdf)

Comment: Oh thank you very much!
I totally forgot about the predicate...
Alright now i got some more options and gotta figure out the right one to go!

Comment: @TomasBy thanks a lot for the link :)!